# How to approach question with variable floor like this one

Tags: number-theory

$$4x^2 - 3 \lfloor x \rfloor ^2 ≥ 9 $$ I don't quite understand how do we approach such questions? Is there an expansion what we need to similar to mod or is there a different method altogether?

Comment: Introduce $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $t=x-n$, so $0\leq t<1$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and you solve $4(n+t)^2-3n^2\geq 9$ subject to these constraints.  Finally bring $n,t$ back together in a single $x$.

Comment: I'd try to find for what $x$-value this expression is equal to $9$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard type of question like this; it looks quite unfamiliar to me.

What I would do to approach this is consider $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$, where $\{x\}$ is the "fractional part". In other words, break $x$ into an integer $n$ and value $y$ with $0\leq y<1$. Then your inequality becomes
$$4(n+y)^2-3n^2\geq 9,$$
which simplifies to $n^2+8ny+y^2\geq 9$. If $n$ is sufficiently large or sufficiently negative then this will be true for all $y\in [0,1)$, and then for each of the few additional values of $n$ you can work out which values of $y$ (if any) in range make the equation true.